# Forward MMS via EMail

Tags: email, mms

I've send someone a pretty long MMS (just text) but he wasn't able to receive. Is there a way to retransmit via EMail. E.g. copy the whole text and paste it into an email instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think so.

Find the message you sent in the "Messaging" app.

Long-press on it.

Choose "Copy message text".

Now run the mail app, compose an email, and in the body of the message, long-press, and choose "Paste" from the pop-up menu.

Comment: Problem is, that I don't have the option "Copy message text". Using stock android 2.3.3 from Samsung with Samsung Galaxy S I9000 as device.

Comment: Incomprehensibly, some stock SMS apps don't have this option. You might have to resort to temporarily installing a 3rd party SMS app like [Go SMS Pro](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jb.gosms&hl=en) long enough to do what you need.